# Rename files using sed and mv

Tags: regex, bash, sed, mv

I want to rename files in the format:

> img_MM-DD-YY_XX.jpg
>
> img_MM-DD-YY_XXX.jpg

to:

> newyears_YYYY-MM-DD_XXX.jpg

Where:

- YYYY = year
- MM = month
- DD = day
- XXX    or XX = photo number

I came up with this script but it isn't working:

```
for filename in ?*.jpg; do
        newFilename=$(echo $filename | \
        sed 's/img_\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)_\([0-9][0-9]\)\./newyears_20\3-\1-\2_0\4./;
                s/img_\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)_\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/newyears_20\3-\1-\2_\4/' -)
        mv $filename $newFilename
done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run your script? What does `for filename in ?*.jpg; do echo $filename; done` return?

Comment: I found the problem. Removing the backslash, "\", after the pipe, "|", makes it work. I guess newlines should not be escaped in bash scripts. Is this correct?

Comment: the backslash isn't necessary, but shouldn't cause any trouble.  Might there have been a space after it, or something like that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this script in bash:

```
for filename in *.jpg; do
  newFilename=$(sed -E 's#img_([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})_(.*)$#newyears_20\3-\2-\1_\4#' <<< "$filename")
  mv "$filename" "$newFilename"
done
```

`sed -E` is supported by `gnu sed` also.

Comment: You also want to use -E on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2):

Without a `for` loop:

```
ls | grep 'jpg$' | sed '
#Save the original filename
h
#Do the replacement
s/img_\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)_\([0-9][0-9]\)\./newyears_20\3-\1-\2_0\4.//
s/img_\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)_\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/newyears_20\3-\1-\2_\4//
#Bring the original filename back
x
G
s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/mv "\1" "\2"' | bash
```

Omit piping to `bash` to see the results before `mv`

Thanks to http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Rename-files-to-lower-case

Comment: Don't parse `ls` output

Comment: @GillesQuenot You might give a reason, it would be helpful.

Comment: @earthdan There are many; this is a very frequently linked FAQ: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

This trivial variant works for me:

```
$ cat mapper
for filename in ?*.jpg
do
    newFilename=$(echo $filename | \
    sed -e 's/img_\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)_\([0-9][0-9]\)\./newyears_20\3-\1-\2_0\4./' \
        -e 's/img_\(.*\)-\(.*\)-\(.*\)_\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/newyears_20\3-\1-\2_\4/')
    echo mv $filename $newFilename
done
$ echo > img_04-23-09_123.jpg
$ echo > img_08-13-08_33.jpg
$ sh mapper
mv img_04-23-09_123.jpg newyears_2009-04-23_123.jpg
mv img_08-13-08_33.jpg newyears_2008-08-13_033.jpg
$
```

The only difference is the use of the explicit `-e` options in place of a semi-colon.

Tested on MacOS X 10.6.7.

Comment: Seems too fragile. Need quoting

Answer (score 0):

I remember messing around with this sort of thing. I found it often useful to create a script that you execute to do what you want:

ie. output of your script would be a file like:

```
mv   file1 file2
mv   file3 file4
.....
mv   fileN fileM
```

To create this, just do a ls | grep  *date pattern* | sed *script to stick mv file1 to file2* > myscript

then just execute ./myscript

This way you have a better look at the intermediate output to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It could be handled by a purely bash script.

```
for j in ?*.jpg
do
  n="newyears_20${j:10:2}-${j:4:2}-${j:7:2}";
  if [ ${j:15:1} = "." ];then
    n="${n}_0${j:13}"
  else
    n="${n}${j:12}"
  fi
  mv $j $n
done
```

Comment: Seems too fragile. Need quoting

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.jpg; do
  n=$(sed -r 's/^(.+)-([^_]+)_(.+)\.jpg/\2-\1_\3.jpg/' <<< "${f#img_}")
  mv "$f" "newyears_20$n"
done
```

The `<<<` is a `bash` feature called a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) and `${f#img_}` removes the `img_` prefix from `$f`. The `sed` expression turns `img_MM-DD-YY_XX.jpg` into `YY-MM-DD_XX.jpg` by isolating `MM-DD` into `\1`, `YY` into `\2` and `XX` into `\3` then forming `\2-\1_\3.jpg`. Note that no quoting is required in the `n` assignment.

For safety, for things like this I actually prefer to use `echo mv` instead of `mv`, so I can see the command this would generate. Then you can remove `echo` or pipe the output to `sh`.

Comment: Seems too fragile. Need quoting

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer for long term value, and so future visitors can learn from your solution, and apply th this knowledge to their own coding issues. Code only answers are frowned upon, and less likely to receive upvotes.

Comment: Fixed the quoting, added explanation. Actually, rewrote the whole thing, since the output was all wrong. I guess I didn't test it at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that. Just use `rename`:

```
rename img_ newyears_ img_*.jpg
```

If you want to use `mv`, try this one-liner:

```
for filename in img*jpg; do mv -v "$filename" "$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/img_/newyears_/'"); done
```

You can also do it without sed:

```
for filename in img*jpg; do mv -v "$filename" "newyears_${filename#*_}"; done
```

Also since bash `for` loops break on whitespaces I would use `find` instead:

```
find . -name "img*.jpg" -maxdepth 1 -exec rename -v img newyears {} \;
```

Tested in CentOS 7

Comment: What works depends on which `rename` utility you are talking about. There are several, but none of them are standard.

Comment: Artificially forcing your three-liner to a one-liner is just making it harder to read. You can then easily replace the newlines with semicolons if you really want to.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think this particular `rename` command  is so simple that it will work in all of them.

Comment: If you can point me towards a definition of _one-liner_ I can be more precise in the future. I have considered everything that doesn't need scrolling in my terminal window a one-liner.

Comment: The conventional formatting is to put the body of the loop in its own block with the `for` line above and the `done` line below it.

Comment: It's not about simplicity; different `rename` utilities have entirely different syntax for what to replace and how to specify the replacement. For example, [the also popular Perl-based `rename`](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_perl_oneliners/perl-rename-command.html) would require `rename 's/^img_/newyears_/' img_*.jpg`. For the record, yours seems to be [the `util-linux` version.](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)

Answer (score -1):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -e 'Dir["img*jpg"].each{|x|File.rename(x,x.gsub(/img_(.*?)-(.*?)-(.*?)\.jpg/,"newyears_20\\2-\\1-\\3.jpg") )}'
```