# Rename files with regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have several files in a direcotry such as :

```
BUSCO_Canis_lupus_BUSCO_v3_451441870_exon_probs.pbl
BUSCO_Canis_lupus_BUSCO_v3_45144182_metapars.cgp.cfg
BUSCO_Canis_lupus_BUSCO_v3_451441E0_weightmatrix.txt
BUSCO_Canis_lupus_BUSCO_v3_451441D0_parameters.cfg
```

and I would like to rename these file by removing the `BUSCO_` part at the begenning and the `_BUSCO_v3_Number_` part in the middle to get :

```
Canis_lupus_exon_probs.pbl
Canis_lupus_metapars.cgp.cfg
Canis_lupus_weightmatrix.txt
Canis_lupus_parameters.cfg
```

I know how to use sed and mv but not how to combine both.

Comment: see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372719/using-sed-to-mass-rename-files and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671773/rename-files-using-sed-and-mv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With perl `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/(?:^BUSCO_|_BUSCO_v3_\d+)//g' *BUSCO*
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good

Comment: Thank bu how can I run the rename fuction direclty in my terminal ?

Comment: Sure, it's the purpose of the command

Comment: What is the output of `rename` ? Is it contains `perlexpr` ?

Comment: When I tap rename in my terminal I get : rename
```-bash: rename: command not found```

Comment: Which OS/distro/version ?

Comment: it is Debian version

Comment: So `apt install rename` It's a _must have_ in the tool box

Comment: Okay I have it, it workd but it still let the numbers ex : ``'Canis_lupus451441870_exon_probs.pbl' ``` and it does not rename it says : ```ancien_file_name  would be renamed to new file name```

Comment: My post is 3 line long, can you eventually read all ?

Comment: oups sorry ...  ok for the -n, so there is still the remaining number issue

Comment: Fixed post accordingly